# Display images from storage Firebase (React#)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm able to get image from my `Storage` into Firebase.

```
const [myImages, setMyImages] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {

      const storage = getStorage();
      const listRef = ref(storage, 'somefolder');

      const allImages = listAll(listRef).then((res) => {

        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {

          getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `somefolder/${itemRef.name}`)).then((img) =>{
            console.log(img) //link to image
            setMyImages(img)
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log('error getting images ', err);
          })

        })

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error getting all files ', error);
      });


    }, []);
```

`img` - it's link to the particular (one) image.
Now I want to save it to `setMyImages` and then render on site:

```
  return (
    <>
       {myImages.map((oneImg) => (
              <img src={oneImg.img} />
       ))}
    </>
  )
```

But something is wrong with `map`

**UPDATE**

```
 const [myImages, setMyImages] = useState([]);

 setMyImages(...img)
```

Comment: You are setting state of one image and map will only work for arrays. So you need to push img to an array and then set that array to the state

Comment: are your "myImages" array looks like your expectation? try to logging "myImages" to ensure that.

Comment: @SulmanAzhar please check if I did it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made litte changes @Sulman code:

1. as I wanted have id and name:

   ```
   listAll(listRef).then(async (res) => {
    let imagesArray = [];
    for (let i in res.items) {
      const itemRef = res.items[i];
      const img = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `somefolder/${itemRef.name}`));
      imagesArray.push({id: i, img: img, name: itemRef.name});
    }
    setMyImages(imagesArray);
   })
   ```
2. render:

   ```
   {(myImages.length > 0) ? myImages.map((oneImg) => (
      <div key={oneImg.id}>
        <img src={oneImg.img} alt={oneImg.name}/>          
      </div>   
      )) : (
        <div>no images</div>
      )
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Following code work for you. I have replaced forEach loop with for-in lopp because of async requests. I created an array before the loop and i am pushing images in it from the loop.

After everything is initialized then i am setting the state with the new array. Which is rendered in JSX like you are doing already

Also if you want to show images as they are loaded then you can do this

```
const [myImages, setMyImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const listRef = ref(storage, "somefolder");

    listAll(listRef)
      .then(async (res) => {
        let imagesArray = [];
        for (let i in res.items) {
          const itemRef = res.items[i];
          const img = await getDownloadURL(
            ref(storage, `somefolder/${itemRef.name}`)
          );
          imagesArray.push(img);
        }
        setMyImages(imagesArray);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error getting all files ", error);
      });
  }, []);



return (
    <>
       {myImages.map((oneImg) => (
              <img src={oneImg.img} />
       ))}
    </>
  )
```

Also if you want to show images as they are loaded then you can do this

```
const [myImages, setMyImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const listRef = ref(storage, "somefolder");

    listAll(listRef)
      .then(async (res) => {
        for (let i in res.items) {
          const itemRef = res.items[i];
          const img = await getDownloadURL(
            ref(storage, `somefolder/${itemRef.name}`)
          );
          setMyImages([...myImages, img]);
        }
   
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error getting all files ", error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: array is filled but then into render it's this `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: second your code it's not working for me, only first

Comment: You don't need id though, you can give keys to your children using map index. i mean its good but you could've also done something like this ```{myImages.map((oneImg, i) => (<img key={i} src={oneImg.img} />))}``` . Also my code should work and what i solved in your question was the initialization of your state. hence answering your question. I would recommend you to do a react course because some of this stuff was really basic. Also do give upvote if my question helped in any way :). The course link: https://www.udemy.com/course/complete-react-developer-zero-to-mastery/
```Happy Coding :)```